Instance is in the EC2 Availability Zone for which the load balancer is not configured to route traffic to
Earlier I created two instances of my microserice running on EC2 in us-east-1c AZ & created a classic load balancer in the same AZ - that worked smoothly.
But when I changed the AZ for the classic load balancer (created a new one in some other AZ), it threw Instance is in the EC2 Availability Zone for which the load balancer is not configured to route traffic to. despite having Cross-zone load balancing ON.
My understanding is Cross-zone load balancing will distribute the traffic to all AZs (not just the ones where it has been pointed to at the time of creation) - but I suspect it distributes traffic evenly to all the instances where the LB node has been created.

I suspect that it will only deliver traffic to instances in AZs where the Load Balancer 'exists'. Cross-zone load balancing simply means that traffic arriving at the Load Balancer in AZ-A can be routed to an instance in AZ-B. However, the Load Balancer still needs to be in both AZs. Try configuring the Load Balancer to be in subnets in both AZs. It won't cost you any extra.

@JohnRotenstein My findings are also on the same line: the LB is required to be in the same AZ as the running instances - the only difference made by cross-zone LB (if enabled) is, it distributes the traffic uniformly among the instances rather than the AZs.

Almost. Think of it like this... Incoming traffic is randomly (or by weight) distributed amongst the AZs. The Load Balancer then randomly (or other) distributes it amongst instances in the same AZ. This means that if there are more instances in one AZ, then traffic is not evenly spread among all instances. However, if cross-zone load balancing is active, then the Load Balancer in one AZ can send the traffic to an instance in a different AZ, thus smoothing out the load if the number of instances in each AZ is different. Or something like that. :)
